# How to join path and filename c as aolumns array output?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a delete method to my user controller which deletes all the uploaded images of the user. I store the files with a filename and path column so they are separated.

```
id path     filename  mime      uploader_id
1  gallery  imagA.jpg image/jpg 1
2  gallery  imagB.jpg image/jpg 1
3  gallery  imagV.jpg image/jpg 2
```

Now I want to use `File::delete($images);` and delete all files of the user at once, but I need a array where the path and filename are joined together. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: DB::table('images')->select(DB::raw('concat(path,"/",filename') as file)->get() ?

Comment: maybe change "->get()" to ->pluck('file')->all(); :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public function delete(int $uploaderId)
{
    $images = DB::table('images')->where('uploader_id', $uploaderId)->get();

    foreach ($images as $i) {
      File::delete($i->path.'/'.$i->filename);
    }

    return // api response or redirect back;
}
```